# SQL- error when creating table with check constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to create a table with sql but getting error of "A symbol name was expected! A reserved keyword can not be used as a column name without backquotes".

```
Create TABLE Tour (  
    Tour_ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    Tour_Title VARCHAR(15) Not NULL,  
    Cost decimal(4,2) DEFAULT '2000.00',   
    CONSTRAINT tour_pk PRIMARY KEY (Tour_ID),  
    CONSTRAINT Ck_cost CHECK Cost BETWEEN 1500 and 2500  
    );
```

Error is on the CHECK statement so i don't know why the error of reserved keyword is showing. Looked everywhere so hopefully not asking a stupid question.

Comment: MySQL does not yet support check constraints.  Yet oddly it lets you put them in.  Don't do it, use a trigger instead.

Comment: The duplicate is not accurate.  The OP is asking about syntax, not why the check constraint itself is not working.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not implement `check` constraints, so there is no utility to including them.  However, it should be parsing them correctly.

I think you are missing parentheses:

```
Create TABLE Tour (  
    Tour_ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    Tour_Title VARCHAR(15) Not NULL,  
    Cost decimal(4,2) DEFAULT '2000.00',   
    CONSTRAINT tour_pk PRIMARY KEY (Tour_ID),  
    CONSTRAINT Ck_cost CHECK (Cost BETWEEN 1500 and 2500) 
);
```

I should emphasize that if you actually want to implement the check, you need to do so in your application or using a trigger.